# jQuery setInterval on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm not primarily a jquery or javascript programmer, there may be a more efficient way to accomplish this, but ultimately I'm after debugging the script failing after 8 seconds in Firefox.

Hovering near one of the command prompts fires jquery script .hover event that initiates a jquery animated sprite.

Works fine in all browsers with the exception of FireFox.  It will play for a collective 8 seconds before it begins to fail.  This is cumulative of each of the 4 zones / scripts.

Is there a way to modify this script to debug that?

(Script below is an excerpt of one of four quadrants.  All scripts used are inline in index for the moment, for easy debugging, just visit the url to see the whole she-bang)

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>

        /* timer functions */
        var intvalBR="";
        function setIntBR(){if(intvalBR===""){
                  intvalBR=window.setInterval("BR()",100);
              }else{
                  stop_IntBR();
              }
            }   

        /* timer reset functions */
        function stop_IntBR(){
                if(intvalBR!==""){
                  window.clearInterval(intvalBR);
                  intvalBR="";

              }
            }

        /* background reset functions */
        function resetBotRight(){
            $("#bottom-right").css({'background-position': '0px 0px'});
        }

        // first frame of animation
        var frame = 1;
        function BR()
        {
                var left = 400 * frame;
                // top stays 0 since all the images are have Y positioned at  0
                var top = 0;


                $('#bottom-right').css('backgroundPosition','-'+left+'px -'+top+'px');

                frame++;
        }

            $("#bottom-right-inside").hover(function(){
                $("#bottom-right-inside").addClass("bottom-right-inside");      
                setIntBR();         
            },
            function(){
                $("#bottom-right-inside").removeClass("bottom-right-inside");
                stop_IntBR();
                resetBotRight();

            });     

        });
            </script>
```

Comment: Please don't pass strings into `setTimeout`/`Interval`. Use anonymous functions or function references (in this case, just `window.setInterval(BR,100)` would work perfectly, be more readable, and be better practice..

Comment: sending strings in fact invokes an `eval` and we all know `eval` is evil.

Comment: Furthermore, ***CACHE YOUR ELEMENTS!!!***, local variables are your friend, even global variables in this case are better than reaching into the DOM each time.

Comment: FF 17.0.1 here, your link seems to work as expected. Spend some time re-saving your images to web-quality (500k for that background is way too big) and optimizing your code like apsillers & rlemon mentioned to help load times on non-dsl internet.